# Confused about two formulas for electric field magnitudes

Tags: electricity

So I am going through my notes and I come across these two equations which both describe electric field magnitudes (I think.)

$$\frac{k q}{r^2}$$

and

$$\frac{Q}{A \epsilon_0}$$

Could someone please clarify these two equations for me. Do they mean the same thing? And when would I use one or the other. Thanks.

Comment: At the moment I am posting this comment, there is no equation in your post.

Answer (score 2):

The second equation is essentially a special case of Gauss's law and could refer to a variety of situations. The first equation happens to be a special case of the second equation.

Gauss's Law says the total of the electric flux out of a closed surface is equal to the charge enclosed by the surface, divided by the electric permittivity ($\epsilon_\circ$). Electric flux is not the same as electric field. Think of flux as the amount of electric field penetrating perpendicularly through a surface. Its units are $\frac{\text{N}\cdot\text{m}^2}{C}$, so if an electric field always points perpendicular to a particular surface, the electric flux through that surface is simply $\Phi_e=Area\times Electric Field$. This means that, in the case of certain geometries where the electric field is always perpendicular to the chosen surface, the Gauss's law equation looks just like the second equation you are asking about. [2](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gaulaw.html)
$$
\Phi_e=AE=\frac{Q}{\epsilon_\circ}
$$

An example of one such geometry where this works is a single charged particular. If we place an imaginary sphere (known as a Gaussian surface) around that particle, everywhere the field lines intersect the surface of that sphere they will be perpendicular to the surface, so our equation works. That example is illustrated below.

[image]

This charged particle example is the context in which we would use the first equation, $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$. To see how find the area we are dealing with.In this case it is the area of the surface of a sphere, which is $A=4\pi r^2$. If we plug that into Gauss's law, remember that Coulomb's constant is related to the electric permittivity by $k=\frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_\circ}$, and solve for the electric field we get the equation:
$$
E = \frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_\circ r^2} = \frac{kq}{r^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

The first one is the [force between two point charges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) and the second one is the [electric field between two uniformly charged plates](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node27.html).

Now you edited your post, so the first one is the [electric field of a point charge](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/epoint.html) $q$.